# How to use shared location of assemblies by multiple applications

Tags: .net, assemblies, gac, appdomain

I've just took over a bunch of windows services (on server no. 1) and web applications (on server no.2) on two servers. All those application use a great deal of the same core libraries. I would like to start fixing that mess and make my life easier. This is the first thing that popped into my head:

There are many libraries there and I'm getting anoyed when I have to:

- update web/windows service application in all locations
- remember to update all applications

Those libraries are not strongly named, and also are preety often recompiled, so I would like to avoid using GAC. Is there any other way to store common assemblies in one directory like **c:\libs\services.core** (on server no.1, and do the same on server no.2)  and force application to look for missing libraries in that location?

Thanks

Comment: You are essentially asking "how do I make this problem ten times worse".  Don't mess with DLL Hell, it will eat you.  AppDomain.AssemblyResolve if you want to try anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, GAC is meant exactly for this scenario even if you want to avoid it. If your assemblies will be very fluent and will require constant updates, this means that they are better of in their private project folders or else it will be impossible to keep track of breaking changes across all projects which depend on the shared assemblies.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to continue this subject in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632390/using-global-assembly-cache-in-real-world-from-development-environment-to-live , help appreciated :)